# Mock ON_CALL return value is ignored when mocked method is called from a thread

Tags: c++, multithreading, unit-testing, googlemock

I have a Mock of a sender and for some reason whenever its called from a thread it doesn't return the set return value (true) , but instead returns the default value (false).

```
ON_CALL(sender, sendMessage(A<MsgType>())).WillByDefault(Return(true));
```

So when this is called by the main process, it rightly returns true, but as soon as it's called from the thread it returns false and gives the default value message on the console.

When stepping through the google mock I can see that when the method is called from the thread the return type container that is supposed to hold the return values is empty but from the main process it contains the return value. In debugging the mock and the container seem to have the correct address though.

Any ideas as to why this might be happening?

Comment: Can you post more details/code? What concurrency API are you using?

Comment: Haha, concurrency API, good one. Win32 threads, baby. As it turns out the issue was caused by an incorrectly structured test case shutdown procedure in legacy code. It simply reset the On_CALL condition before the application (including the thread) had shutdown.

Comment: How can I close this question?